# Local network blocks outgoing packets from devices occasionaly

Tags: ip, router, modem, dhcp

My internet stops sending outgoing packets a lot of times during the day, and it lasts 8 to 13 seconds.

Example: in Discord I keep listening others, but they can't hear me. Other softwares have the same behavior.

In my house there are 4 routers, and 1 ISP Modem, all in the same subnet.
All routers have DHCP turned off, and the Modem is responsible por the DHCP.
Modem is 192.168.0.1, and the 4 routers from .2 to .5.

I would like to know if this could be a DHCP configuration problem, or a ISP problem! Any ideas?

I tried connecting my PC to all routers, and even the Modem, and the problem happened in all tries.

Answer (score 1):

You have done your troubleshooting well.  By observing the problem without any routers in the mix, you've shown that your trouble is in the modem or, more likely, the ISP network behind it.

One more thing to rule out: completely disconnect your routers from your modem, switch them off, and repeat your test directly connected, with Ethernet not WiFi, to the modem.

If you still have the problem you have proven the problem is with your machine, the modem, or the ISP network.

If the problem goes away in that situation it's possible that some other machine somewhere on your network is occasionally blasting data at the modem.

Four routers sounds like an overly complex setup. The typical modem connects to only one router. Routers actually route packets from an upstream network (your ISP) to a downstream network (your building's LAN). If there's confusion about which router is supposed to do that, frankly it's amazing that anything works. If three of your four are configured as WiFi access points that's OK.

The typical modem doesn't offer DHCP service to its downstream LAN network, because it doesn't know about a network behind it, only one device, your router.

Some ISPs provide combination modem / router boxes. Maybe that's what you have. You may want to review your network configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't turn off the others routers to test, because there are 13 other people in the house ): Is there a way I can analyze the network to check what happens during the outgoing problem? (I have admin access to all routers and modem). I will also study about turning the router to access point.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tracert` command in the command line to see if your packets are travelling through all these routers. Maybe it will solve the problem or at least displays if the problem is caused in the routing. Or try to see if the problem is caused in a wrong **default gateway** to the device.

Comment: C:\>tracert 192.168.0.1

Tracing route to 192.168.0.1 over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
This was the result of the command (tried with all ips in the network  same result)

All routers are configured as Access Point, and the ISP Modem is the only DHCP server enabled.
Yesterday I found a IP conflict with a chromecast and a router. Solved the conflict by changing the router IP, but the problem continues...

Comment: try using the command for an ip outside the network to see if the packet travells all the way up.  And as i said maybe there is an error to your default gateway. If error occurs try communicating with your ISP.